# How to deploy in Spark Java

Tags: java, spark-java

I prepared an app and I want to deploy it on a Spark Java backend (the app is a React frontend). I searched online and I only find how to build the two things separately but I can't find how to bind them: how can I do it? (Please be patient, I'm new to Spark).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Java Spark is compact web server. So the CDN on the React app still applies, you just need to link your React app to your Java Spark backend afterwards.

---

Old answer:

A React app has nothing to do with Spark. [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) is a unified analytics engine for large-scale data processing.

If you want to deploy your React app in a scalable fashion, use a CDN, for example AWS S3 + Cloudfront, like in [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-guide-to-deploying-your-react-app-with-aws-s3-including-https-a-custom-domain-a-cdn-and-58245251f081) article.

Comment: I'm using the Spark java framework, not Apache Spark ( http://sparkjava.com/ )

Comment: The fact is that I don't know how to do it. It seems like I'm obliged to use some cloaud platforms in between but I want to deploy it directly into Spark

Comment: Well you need to deploy it somewhere, if you are not using a cloud service, what are you using?

Comment: Spark framework has an embedded Jetty web server, I thought I could use it

Comment: For local development, yes. Just do your backend API requests from React to the Jetty server.

Comment: Exactly. but now I need to deploy this thing and I need to deliver it so I can't use the local jetty